# Retrieve picklist field value dependencies based on recordtype

Tags: apex, record-type, dependent-picklist, field-dependencies

I want to retrieve picklist field values based on recordtype dependencies.

I know there's a way to achieve this via MetadataAPI but is there anyway to accomplish this with REST API call/s?

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ui-api (a REST API) to [Get Values for All Picklist Fields of a Record Type](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.224.0.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_resources_picklist_values_collection.htm), or [describe the object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_sobject_describe.htm) and use the [validFor property](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/201799/2984) of each picklist.