# How I can Make Dependent Picklist Based on the RecordType In visuaforce Page

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component

I have two PickList Fields that is order_type (Controlling Field) and Order_subtype (Dependent Field) and want to show an Order_subtype value based on the record type as well as an order_type field value.

For example:- for record type Type_1, if the Order_type value is Option_1, the available Order_subtype options are A and B. For record type Type_2, if the Order_type value is Option_1, the available Order_subtype options are E and F.

I have tried but it shows me an error like [image]

But this is error is fix when I added the controlling field in the VF Page like the below code line but I am able to get order_subtype value.

```
<apex:inputField id="categoryPicList" value="{!orderObj.Order_Type__c}"/>
```

Apex code

```
 public void getRecordTypeList(){
    
    List<RecordType> rtList = [SELECT Id,Name FROM RecordType WHERE SObjectType='SVMXC__Service_Order__c' ];
    recordTypeList.add(new SelectOption('--None--', '--None--'));
    for(RecordType rt : rtList)
    {
        recordTypeList.add(new SelectOption(rt.Id, rt.Name));
    }
    system.debug('recordTypeList'+recordTypeList);
}

public void getPickListValues(){
    
    if(selectedRT != null){
        orderObj = new SVMXC__Service_Order__c(RecordTypeId = selectedRT);
    }
}
```

VF page

```
 <apex:selectList value="{!selectedRT}" size="1" multiselect="false" label="Record Type" title="Record Type" id="recordTypes"> 
                <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!getPickListValues}" reRender="categoryPicList" />
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!RecordTypeList}" /> 
            </apex:selectList>
            <apex:inputField id="categoryPicList" value="{!orderObj.Order_Subtype__c}"/>
```

But if I write order_Type in place of order_subtype

```
<apex:inputField id="categoryPicList" value="{!orderObj.Order_Type__c}"/>
```

it shows order_type values based on the record type.
Please help to show the order_subtype values based on the record type and order_type value.
Thank you.

Comment: related: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/359713/retrieve-picklist-field-value-dependencies-based-on-recordtype